# Mac OS X/Cocoa: create "docked" sidebar that reduces maximizable area, like the Dock

Tags: macos, cocoa

When the OS X dock is shown, it "reserves" some screen area and prevents maximized windows from going behind the dock when maximized. How do I make my own Cocoa application do the same?

Answer (score 1):

A window's "maximizable area" is based on the screen's `visibleFrame`.

`[[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame]`

> The returned rectangle is always based on the current user-interface settings and does not include the area currently occupied by the dock and menu bar.
>
> Because it is based on the current user -interface settings, the returned rectangle can change between calls and should not be cached.
>   The rectangle defining the portion of the screen in which it is currently safe to draw your application content.

There is no mention of being able to adjust this `visibleFrame` rectangle, so I do not think you will have any success influencing the "global" Zoom size.

However, if you only want to adjust the Zoomed size of *your app's* window, return a smaller rectangle in the `NSWindowDelegate` method `windowWillUseStandardFrame:defaultFrame:`.

> The standard frame for a window should supply the size and location that are “best” for the type of information shown in the window, taking into account the available display or displays. For example, the best width for a window that displays a word-processing document is the width of a page or the width of the display, whichever is smaller. The best height can be determined similarly. On return from this method, the zoom: method modifies the returned standard frame, if necessary, to fit on the current screen.

This will allow you to take into account a "docked sidebar" when Zooming *your app's windows*. Other apps will be resized on top of the docked sidebar.